# JMS web application with Eclipse and WebSphere Application Server

Tags: eclipse, jms, websphere-7

I am new to JMS and WAS. I am grateful if someone provides any reference that helps me to create a web application in eclipse with JMS and WAS 7.0.

Also want to get answers for below questions..

1. How to inject ConnectionFactory or Destination object (created in WAS) into application using jndi?
2. How to install and run JMS web application on WAS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide on the provider for JMS. It could be WebSphere MQ, the JMS provider that comes inbuilt with WAS or some other provider too.

Refer to the redbooks https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg247770.html?Open.

1. You can use InitialContext to lookup connection factory and Destination.
2. You can deploy the JMS app just like any other app. But ensure that JNDI objects are configured.

This is also a nice info-center to use for reference: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodconn/v1r0m0/topic/com.ibm.scenarios.wmqwasusing.doc/topics/scenario_overview.htm